# XML Parsing Error: no root element found in ASP.NET Core 2.0 API

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've encountered this problem, and I couldn't figure it out. I'm using ASP.NET Core 2 and Ajax.

This is what the JavaScript debugger says:

> XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location:
>   http://localhost:52617/api/favorites/ Line Number 1, Column 1:

This is my JavaScript code:

```
$(".js-toggle-fav").click(function (e) {
    function sendPost() {
        console.log("inside post send");

        var button = $(e.target);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost:52617/api/Favorites/",
            data: {"EventId": @Model.Event.EventId},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        });
    }

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:52617/api/favorites/@Model.Event.EventId", function (data) {
        if (data == null) {
            console.log("fav is null");
            sendPost();
            fav.addClass(toggling);
            fav.text("unfav");
        }
        else {
            console.log("fav is NOT null");
            sendPost();
            fav.removeClass(toggling);
            fav.text("fav");
        }
    );
});
```

And my API:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostFavorite([FromBody] FavoriteDto favorite)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ModelState.ValidationState.ToString());
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    var uid = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
    var fav = await _context.Favourites.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.EventId == favorite.EventId && x.UserId == uid);
    if (fav == null)
    {
        _context.Favourites.Add(new Favorite { EventId = favorite.EventId, UserId=uid });
    }
    else
    {
        _context.Favourites.Remove(fav);
    }
    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException)
    {
        if (FavoriteExists(favorite.EventId))
        {
            return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return Ok(favorite);
}
```

When I do this with Postman or any restclient, everything works like a charm! With Ajax, that's not the case.

> NOTES:
>
> - In the same `.cshtml` file, there's more jQuery and JavaScript code which does something like this, and it's just working! All the solutions
>     I've checked on the internet didn't work, unfortunately.
> - The Get methods (for returning List, or single element are working!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is coming from

```
data: {"EventId": @Model.Event.EventId},
```

Instead of passing it in directly, use JSON.Stringify

```
var payload = {EventId: @Model.Event.EventId};
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: "http://localhost:52617/api/Favorites/",
       data: JSON.stringify(payload),
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      });
```

I'm assuming your FavoriteDto class looks something like this

```
public class FavoriteDto
{
   public int EventId { get; set; }
}
```

The reason why you were getting an xml error is that the controller action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostFavorite([FromBody] FavoriteDto favorite)
```

could not parse 'favorite' so it was never initialised and was null. You then return ok(null) which caused a parsing error on your client side ajax when it recieved the response back from your server.

Comment: Mr. Karimabadi! It worked !! But I'm now getting crazy by the fact that another button in my site is working with the approach  I've made but this one didn't, any idea why did that code work (Note it does have more than one property in that code of mine)?

Comment: Are the other requests, GET requests? If so, that would be why they worked because you were never posting any data. The problem came because, again, favorite, was not initialized beacuse it could not be parsed. I suspect all your other requests dont post data and are POST requests???

Comment: Actually they are POST requests! This is what've made me so mad :D .

Comment: Do the other post endpoint have the [FromBody] attribute?? If they do not, the favorite object does get initialized, but it only has data for the default values, so it appears that you have a favourite object but if you look closely, the object does not have the data that you sent it

Comment: I see now! Thanks for your help and explanation ^_^

Comment: I had the same issue with Firefox. I tried JSON.stringify(), but the error stays. The API method is "void" and obviously Firefox doesn't like it. It expects something in return. If I change the method to string and return some dummy string, the error goes away.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error during a `DELETE` call to an ASP.Net Core 2.1 Web API. I removed the `[FromBody]` from the model that was expected from the `DELETE`call, such as

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(MyModel body)
{
  // Just an example
  await DoSomeWork(body);

  return StatusCode(200);
}
```

but that did not solve the problem. However, after I returned some content with `StatusCode`, in this example just a simple string, the error was gone. So the following code should avoid the error in Firefox:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(MyModel body)
{
  // Just an example
  await DoSomeWork(body);

  return StatusCode(200, "Deletion Successfull");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers, this error can also happen if jQuery ajax gets an empty string response where it expects valid JSON, or no content at all.

Check the value of the `data` in the `done` callback, if it's an empty string `""` rather than `undefined`, you'll have to fix your server to return status code `204 (No Content)` instead of an `200 (OK)` with no content.

In WebAPI2 this would mean returning `StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent)` instead of `Ok()`.